# Why does Convert.ChangeType take an object parameter?

Tags: .net, iconvertible, changetype

The [`Convert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.aspx) class has been in existence since .NET 1.0. The [`IConvertible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.aspx) interface has also existed since this time.

The [`Convert.ChangeType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx) method *only* works on objects of types that implement `IConvertible` (in fact, unless I'm mistaken, *all* of the conversion methods provided by the `Convert` class are this way). So why is the parameter type `object`?

In other words, instead of this:

```
public object ChangeType(object value, Type conversionType);
```

Why isn't the signature this?

```
public object ChangeType(IConvertible value, Type conversionType);
```

Just seems strange to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking in reflector you can see the top of `ChangeType(object, Type, IFormatProvider)`, which is what's called under the covers:

```
public static object ChangeType(object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
{
  //a few null checks...
  IConvertible convertible = value as IConvertible;
  if (convertible == null)
  {
    if (value.GetType() != conversionType)
    {
        throw new InvalidCastException(Environment.GetResourceString("InvalidCast_IConvertible"));
    }
    return value;
  }
```

So it looks like an object of a type that *doesn't* implement `IConvertible` but already *is* the destination type will just return the original object.

Granted it looks like this is the *only* exception to the value needing to implement `IConvertible`, but it is an exception, and looks like the reason the parameter is `object` instead.

---

Here's a quick LinqPad test for this case:

```
void Main()
{
  var t = new Test();
  var u = Convert.ChangeType(t, typeof(Test));
  (u is IConvertible).Dump();   //false, for demonstration only
  u.Dump();                     //dump of a value Test object
}

public class Test {
  public string Bob;
}
```

Comment: I guess this does seem to be the only possible explanation... doesn't it seem odd to you, though, that the designers would've considered the behavior "can take an object and convert it to the same type" even worth supporting? I mean, what would this ever be used for?

Comment: @Dan - I think ObjectDatasource uses it internally IIRC, I guess they preferred the check inside instead of one outside? I agree it doesn't seem very useful.

Comment: It's unfortunate since converting a type to its own base type should totally not need IConvertible, and there's newer .NET code now baking in this hidden need for IConvertibles in situations where it could just use the object, unconverted.